# Multiple Authors per post and filter post by author

Tags: author

How can i assign multiple authors to a post and only show posts by author.

Im currently using the following to get post by the current logged in user. But it only allows me to have one author.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'author__in' => $authors, 'post_type' => 'Contacts', 'numberposts' => 30, 'orderby' => 'date') ); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
// -----
endwhile;
```

HI need to be able to assign any amount of authors and allow each user to see all post where they are the author.

Answer (score -1):

Try this plugin it's the easy way of doing what you want
[co-authors-plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/)

Comment: link only answers are not real answers. In this case the link is not even to the plugin itself

Comment: Thank you @MarkKaplun I didn't know, I'm still learning as I go along try to help

Comment: If you are going to recommend a plugin at least link directly to it ;) than you can explain or add additional resources on how to use it, but in general just having a link is not a good thing. You can add such recomendations as comments to the questions

Comment: Ok I understand I will correct it right now

Comment: @MarkKaplun I just updated the link